# Cannot access application deployed in tomcat on Ubuntu Linux server

Tags: linux, tomcat

I deployed the application in tomcat on Ubuntu linux server, and its port is 7777, but I cannot access it by http:IP_ADDRESS:7777/project. I don't know why. Is it caused by different gateways?

Comment: shouldn't it be http//:IP_ADDRESS:7777 in the first place ? with the `//`

Comment: Yes, I used ip like yours to test. But also cannot access.

Comment: Is tomcat on that machine reachable ? what error do you get ? 404 from tomcat ? or connection timeout from browser ? how did you configure your context ? can you show your web.xml ?